# Закрытие элемента по клику вне его области - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт загрузки кода самого меню в уже созданный блок `.avatar-menu-box`. + есть отображение этого блока при нажатии на определенную кнопку `.avatar-menu` при помощи класса `.avatar-show`  котором прописано для меню `display: block`
Как в моем случае сделать закрытие элемента по клику вне его области?

```
$('.avatar-menu').on('click', function () {
   $('.avatar-menu-box').load('frend');
   $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('avatar-show');
});
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83+%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял что нужно сделать, то можно сделать, что бы меню закрывалось по клику на любое место, кроме самого меню и кнопки. Тогда можно использовать `event.stopPropagation()`.  https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Например

```
$(document).click(function(){
     скрываем меню
})

$(document).on('click', '.avatar-menu, .avatar-menu-box', function(event){
      //предотвращаем скрытие меню, по нажатии на кнопку и на само меню
      event.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Отмечу ваш ответ как правильный, как только мне предоставит stackoverflow такую возможность. (2 дня надо ждать))) + Я ниже написал код, который в моём случае заработал как я и хотел. Вдруг кому надо будет : )

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо пользователю [Maxim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/508886/maxim)

Готовый код выглядит вот так:

```
$('.avatar-menu').on('click', function () {
   $('.avatar-menu-box').load('frend');
   $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('avatar-show');
});
// ниже, новый рабочий код
$(document).on('click', function () {
   $('.avatar-menu').parent().parent().removeClass('avatar-show');
});
$(document).on('click', '.avatar-menu, .avatar-menu-box', function(event){
   //предотвращаем скрытие меню, по нажатии на кнопку и на само меню
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```